# Express JS : Params undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have following route in my express js

```
app.get('/fetchnotes/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    connection.query('SELECT * from dn_notes where id=?',[id], function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (!err) {
            res.json(rows);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

AND i have the following code in HTML file which will call the fetchnotes with parameter

```
<a class="item item-body" href="#/app/fetchnotes/{{notes.id}}">
    {{notes.detail}}
</a>
```

**app.js**

```
.state('app.fetchsinglenote', {
    url: '/fetchnotes/:notelistid',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/notelists.html',
            controller: 'SingleNoteListCtrl'
        }
    }
});
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller('SingleNoteListCtrl', function($scope, $state, $resource, $stateParams ) {
    $scope.fetchnotes = {};
    var id = $stateParams .id;
    var Fetchnotes1 = $resource('http://localhost:8080/fetchnotes/'+ id);
    Fetchnotes1.query(function(results) {
        $scope.fetchnotes = results;
    })
})
```

Node server is run thru port 8080.

However i get the value of `undefined` from the console at line `console.log(id);` in my express js file. Where is the problem guys?

Comment: where is your ``{{notes.id}}`` come from?

Comment: from mysql  database, that item has link  `http://localhost:8100/#/app/fetchnotes/2` or `http://localhost:8100/#/app/fetchnotes/1` and so on, the problem when i click the link, it give `undefined` where i should get the value of the id such as `1` or `2`

Comment: what is the result of ``$stateParams.id`` in your controller?

Comment: its `undefined` as well, what is the problem?

Comment: so in your ``var Fetchnotes1 = $resource('http://localhost:8080/fetchnotes/'+ id);`` 
Fetchnotes1 is undefined, ``$scope.fetchnotes`` also undefined, where you put ``$scope.fetchnotes``?

Comment: my bad, it should be `$stateParams,notelistid` instead of `$stateParams.id`, sorry guys and thanks @DonaldWu

Answer (score 0):

$resource('http://localhost:8080/fetchnotes/:notelistid', { notelistid: '@_id' },
Try Sending this way

Comment: Please clean up your answer. Explain what you're doing and format your code properly.